# Javascript global array becomes undefined when used on other html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have declared some global variables along with global array in my firstpage.hmtl's script and these global variables and array are accessible everywhere on this page and working fine on this page. And I want to use the values of window.arr[] on all pages of the application but it is showing undefined on all other pages of application

When I redirect from firstpage.html to secondpage.html then I try to get the values of these global variables but here the issue arise because just window.name is working on second page other than that every global variable's value is undefined

I have tried many names for these global variables but just one of them is working which is window.name other than that everything is undefined.

**firstpage.html**

```
    window.name = "john";
    window.car = "BMW";
    window.arr = [];

    $(".hotels").click(function () {
            arr.push('hotels');
            console.log("name = " + window.name); //working, prints "name = john"
            console.log("car = " + window.car); //working, prints "car = BMW"
            console.log("arr = " + window.arr); //working, prints "arr = hotels"
    }
```

**secondpage.html**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("arr = " + window.arr); //not working here, prints "arr = undefined"
    console.log("car = " + window.car); //not working here, prints "car = undefined"
    console.log("name = " + window.name); //working, prints "name = john"

});
```

Comment: I think you want to try session storage for what you're trying to do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Global variables are not expected to be shared between page loads;

Comment: Every page has it's own window instance. Take a look at using localStorage

Comment: Also not a good idea to use `window.name` for a variable as it is also used by browser and should be reserved for unique windows

Comment: @JasonB thanks man session storage is the suitable solution in my situation

Comment: @charlietfl I wasn't using window.name as variable just used in this demo. because I was curious that why just window.name is working and everything else is no and I didn't knew that it was used by browser :)

Comment: Understand...just letting you know it is a default global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different pages, you cannot pass data like this. But you can save it in localStorage f.e. and use it from there.